# JPA2:i persist a entity ,there is no exception but the data is not saved in database

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I am using EJB to write a CRUD demo code on netbeans..when i write a code that can save data into database ,there is no error and exception but the data is not saved in database
code:

entitybean:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "book_book")
    @XmlRootElement
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "BookBook.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM BookBook b"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "BookBook.findByIsbn", query = "SELECT b FROM BookBook b WHERE b.isbn = :isbn"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "BookBook.findByDealTotal", query = "SELECT b FROM BookBook b WHERE b.dealTotal = :dealTotal"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "BookBook.findBySaleTotal", query = "SELECT b FROM BookBook b WHERE b.saleTotal = :saleTotal"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "BookBook.findBySalePrice", query = "SELECT b FROM BookBook b WHERE b.salePrice = :salePrice"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "BookBook.findByDealPrice", query = "SELECT b FROM BookBook b WHERE b.dealPrice = :dealPrice")})
    public class BookBook implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
    //    @NotNull
        @Column(name = "isbn")
        private Long isbn;
        @Column(name = "deal_total")
        private Integer dealTotal;
        @Column(name = "sale_total")
        private Integer saleTotal;
        @Column(name = "sale_price")
        private Integer salePrice;
        @Column(name = "deal_price")
        private Integer dealPrice;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "isbn")
        private List<BookBookdetail> bookBookdetailList;
```

DAClass(not a sessionbean):

```
 EntityManagerFactory factory=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BookXPU");
    EntityManager em=factory.createEntityManager();

      public long  createBook(Long isbn, Integer dealTotal, Integer saleTotal, Integer salePrice, Integer dealPrice){
       BookBook book=new BookBook();
       book.setDealTotal(dealTotal);
       book.setSalePrice(salePrice);
       book.setDealTotal(dealTotal);
       book.setDealPrice(dealPrice);
       book.setIsbn(isbn);
       List<BookBookdetail> list=new ArrayList<BookBookdetail>();
       book.setBookBookdetailList(null);
       em.persist(book);


       Query query =em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM BookBook b WHERE b.isbn = :isbn");
       query.setParameter("isbn",book);
       List list1=query.getResultList();
           for (Iterator it = list1.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
               BookBookDetail book1 = (BookBookDetail)it.next();
               list.add(book1);
           }
           book.setBookBookdetailList(list);
       em.merge(book);
       return  book.getIsbn();


       }
```

Thanks...

Comment: i try to test this code in a sessionbean and success...

Comment: So, you did try and it works? Is there any problem with this code? You can't see the result in the database or using the query in the code?

Comment: if this code in a common java class..i can't see the result in the database...i had to change the common class into stateless sessionbean...and i can see the result then ..but can you tell me how can i change the code in order to be success in common java class

Answer (score 1):

Your entities are not persisted because **you're not flushing the entities to your database**.

If you use your code in a Java SE than you should do:

```
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
// persist, merge, etc. - operations which needs to be in the Tx...
tx.close();
```

Without it, you're not giving a sign that the data you've changed should be flushed to the underlying database.

When you've moved your code into an EJB you were using a JTA transactions (implicitly). Therefore, an EntityManager's transaction was a part of the JTA transaction. By default every method of an EJB is a single JTA transaction.

Now, combining these pieces of information it occurs that **by marking your class as an EJB you've flushed the data to the underlying database**.

HTH.